# Getting empty file from response and not able to save the file in django models class

Tags: python, django

My task is to create `.xlsx` file of late employees and return it to download at the same time I should create an object for every day with fields `day` and `list`(`.xlsx`). My implementation code is:

```
...
    file = excel_file.save('my_data.xlsx')

    day = Day.objects.create(days_date=timezone.now(), days_file=File(file))

    response = HttpResponse(file, content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',)
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename={date}-attendance.xlsx'.format(date=timezone.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),)

    return response
```

There are no error messages but the file from `response` is empty, for the class object doesn't exist

my `models.py`:

```
class Day(models.Model):
    days_date = models.DateField()
    days_file = models.FileField(upload_to='day/')

    def __str__(self):
        return '{date}'.format(date=timezone.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

I am using `django==2.2 openpyxl` and I am using `Linux ubuntu OS`

Comment: Does `excel_file.save` actually has a returned value? or it just saves the file?

Comment: It saves the file, before I used `excel_file.save(response)` and it returned the file and now I should save it to the model, I am using `openpyxl`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you should have your file as a **stram** to be able to pass it as a django *response*; as stated in the [docs](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#saving-as-a-stream), you should have this in your `views.py`:

```
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
from openpyxl import Workbook

    #...
    with NamedTemporaryFile() as tmp:
        file = excel_file.save(tmp.name)
        tmp.seek(0)
        stream = tmp.read()

        day = Day.objects.create(days_date=timezone.now(), days_file=File(file))
        response = HttpResponse(stream, content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',)
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename={date}-attendance.xlsx'.format(date=timezone.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),)

        return response
```

Comment: It's not saving the file to model class

Comment: Ok, does the _download_ part works as expected? or you still get an empty output?

Comment: It's working, Thank you! I think I will find another way of saving it.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this link will help you [Save and close an Excel file after adding data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31681154/save-and-close-an-excel-file-after-adding-data), you need to Capitalize the 's' on the save() method

Comment: I am using `openpyxl` and there is no Save() mehtod. I think I will use it cause there are many functionalities that I need